# How password is encrypted in Django 1.5.1?

Tags: django

How password is encrypted in Django 1.5.1? (it's SHA1, SHA256 or md5?). I can't find this in the doc.

Comment: The answer may be trivially googlable, but does that really warrant so many downvotes? The question is reasonably clear and the wording seems OK -  SO seeks to be a canonical source.

Answer (score 2):

I googled your question and ended up with the answer in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/passwords/

```
By default, Django uses the PBKDF2 algorithm with a SHA256 hash
```

Put in some more effort before posting! =)

Comment: Additionally, a SHA-256 HMAC is used for PBKDF2.